# How to handle or store multivalued dimensions in hierarchy in snowflake?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, dimensional-modeling

I am having a scenario where I have multivalued dimensions and its hierarchy in tableau reports and I have to keep the data such that tableau does not make any wired sql or data loading also simple and future extendable.

I have dimension as below:

```
|----------+------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------|
| Product  | Product_category                                     | Product_Weight_GM     |
|----------+------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------|
| Rice Bag | medium grains,small grain,long grain,small grain     | 1000,5000,10000,25000 |
| Wheat    | small grain,medium grains,normal grain,medium grains | 100,200,500,800       |
|----------+------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------|
```

So Product weight is a hierarchy I could go via what strategy of dimensional model.

[image: Here is more detailed hierarchy]

Answer (score 0):

That data doesn't seem hierarchical to me. There is no relationship defined between each (grain size?) that I can see. Also, you seem to have some grain sizes listed multiple times within each row which doesn't seem right. Without having more context of what a "Product" is then I'd suggest something like his:

```
|----------+------------------+-------------------|
| Product  | Product_category | Product_Weight_GM |
|----------+------------------+-------------------|
| Rice Bag | medium grains    |              1000 |
| Rice Bag | small grain      |              5000 |
| Rice Bag | long grain       |             10000 |
| Rice Bag | small grain      |             25000 |
| Wheat    | small grain      |               100 |
| Wheat    | medium grains    |               200 |
| Wheat    | normal grain     |               500 |
| Wheat    | medium grains    |               800 |
|----------+------------------+-------------------|
```

Comment: Updated the hierarchy details above please check if I store that way it will be too difficult to manage.